# istio:error installer PersistentVolumeClaim "istio-jaeger-pvc" is invalid

Tags: istio

I'm trying to run `istioctl install istio-config.yaml` command within CodeBuild on AWS but I get this error:

> error installer PersistentVolumeClaim "istio-jaeger-pvc" is invalid:
> spec.resources.requests.storage: Forbidden: field can not be less than
> previous value

even though I don't have the path `spec.resources.requests.storage` in my configuration file!
This is the content of my file:

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  addonComponents:
    grafana:
      enabled: true
      k8s:
        replicaCount: 1
    istiocoredns:
      enabled: false
    kiali:
      enabled: true
      k8s:
        replicaCount: 1
    prometheus:
      enabled: true
      k8s:
        replicaCount: 1
    tracing:
      enabled: true
  components:
    base:
      enabled: true
    citadel:
      enabled: false
      k8s:
        strategy:
          rollingUpdate:
            maxSurge: 100%
            maxUnavailable: 25%
    cni:
      enabled: false
    egressGateways:
    - enabled: true
      k8s:
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 40Mi
      name: istio-egressgateway
    ingressGateways:
    - enabled: true
      k8s:
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 40Mi
        service:
          ports:
          - name: status-port
            port: 15020
            targetPort: 15020
          - name: http2
            port: 80
            targetPort: 8080
          - name: https
            port: 443
            targetPort: 8443
          - name: tcp
            port: 31400
            targetPort: 31400
          - name: tls
            port: 15443
            targetPort: 15443
        serviceAnnotations:
          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn/to/cert"
          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "http"
          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
      name: istio-ingressgateway
    istiodRemote:
      enabled: false
    pilot:
      enabled: true
      k8s:
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: GODEBUG
          value: gctrace=1
        - name: PILOT_TRACE_SAMPLING
          value: "100"
        - name: CONFIG_NAMESPACE
          value: istio-config
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /ready
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 3
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 100Mi
        strategy:
          rollingUpdate:
            maxSurge: 100%
            maxUnavailable: 25%
    policy:
      enabled: false
      k8s:
        env:
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        hpaSpec:
          maxReplicas: 5
          metrics:
          - resource:
              name: cpu
              targetAverageUtilization: 80
            type: Resource
          minReplicas: 1
          scaleTargetRef:
            apiVersion: apps/v1
            kind: Deployment
            name: istio-policy
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 100Mi
        strategy:
          rollingUpdate:
            maxSurge: 100%
            maxUnavailable: 25%
    telemetry:
      enabled: false
      k8s:
        env:
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: GOMAXPROCS
          value: "6"
        hpaSpec:
          maxReplicas: 5
          metrics:
          - resource:
              name: cpu
              targetAverageUtilization: 80
            type: Resource
          minReplicas: 1
          scaleTargetRef:
            apiVersion: apps/v1
            kind: Deployment
            name: istio-telemetry
        replicaCount: 1
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 4800m
            memory: 4G
          requests:
            cpu: 50m
            memory: 100Mi
        strategy:
          rollingUpdate:
            maxSurge: 100%
            maxUnavailable: 25%
  hub: docker.io/istio
  meshConfig:
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
    defaultConfig:
      tracing:
        sampling: 100
      proxyMetadata: {}
    disablePolicyChecks: false
    enablePrometheusMerge: false
  profile: demo
  tag: 1.6.3
  values:
    base:
      validationURL: ""
    clusterResources: true
    gateways:
      istio-egressgateway:
        autoscaleEnabled: false
        env: {}
        name: istio-egressgateway
        secretVolumes:
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/egressgateway-certs
          name: egressgateway-certs
          secretName: istio-egressgateway-certs
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/egressgateway-ca-certs
          name: egressgateway-ca-certs
          secretName: istio-egressgateway-ca-certs
        type: ClusterIP
        zvpn: {}
      istio-ingressgateway:
        applicationPorts: ""
        autoscaleEnabled: false
        debug: info
        domain: ""
        env: {}
        meshExpansionPorts:
        - name: tcp-pilot-grpc-tls
          port: 15011
          targetPort: 15011
        - name: tcp-istiod
          port: 15012
          targetPort: 15012
        - name: tcp-citadel-grpc-tls
          port: 8060
          targetPort: 8060
        - name: tcp-dns-tls
          port: 853
          targetPort: 8853
        name: istio-ingressgateway
        secretVolumes:
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs
          name: ingressgateway-certs
          secretName: istio-ingressgateway-certs
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-ca-certs
          name: ingressgateway-ca-certs
          secretName: istio-ingressgateway-ca-certs
        type: LoadBalancer
        zvpn: {}
    global:
      arch:
        amd64: 2
        ppc64le: 2
        s390x: 2
      configValidation: true
      controlPlaneSecurityEnabled: true
      defaultNodeSelector: {}
      defaultPodDisruptionBudget:
        enabled: true
      defaultResources:
        requests:
          cpu: 10m
      enableHelmTest: false
      imagePullPolicy: ""
      imagePullSecrets: []
      istioNamespace: istio-system
      istiod:
        enableAnalysis: false
        enabled: true
      jwtPolicy: first-party-jwt
      logAsJson: false
      logging:
        level: default:info
      meshExpansion:
        enabled: false
        useILB: false
      meshNetworks: {}
      mountMtlsCerts: false
      multiCluster:
        clusterName: ""
        enabled: false
      network: ""
      omitSidecarInjectorConfigMap: false
      oneNamespace: false
      operatorManageWebhooks: false
      pilotCertProvider: istiod
      priorityClassName: ""
      proxy:
        autoInject: enabled
        clusterDomain: cluster.local
        componentLogLevel: misc:error
        enableCoreDump: false
        envoyStatsd:
          enabled: false
        excludeIPRanges: ""
        excludeInboundPorts: ""
        excludeOutboundPorts: ""
        image: proxyv2
        includeIPRanges: '*'
        logLevel: warning
        privileged: false
        readinessFailureThreshold: 30
        readinessInitialDelaySeconds: 1
        readinessPeriodSeconds: 2
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 2000m
            memory: 1024Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 40Mi
        statusPort: 15020
        tracer: zipkin
      proxy_init:
        image: proxyv2
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 10Mi
      sds:
        token:
          aud: istio-ca
      sts:
        servicePort: 0
      tracer:
        datadog:
          address: $(HOST_IP):8126
        lightstep:
          accessToken: ""
          address: ""
        stackdriver:
          debug: false
          maxNumberOfAnnotations: 200
          maxNumberOfAttributes: 200
          maxNumberOfMessageEvents: 200
        zipkin:
          address: ""
      trustDomain: cluster.local
      useMCP: false
    grafana:
      accessMode: ReadWriteMany
      contextPath: /grafana
      dashboardProviders:
        dashboardproviders.yaml:
          apiVersion: 1
          providers:
          - disableDeletion: false
            folder: istio
            name: istio
            options:
              path: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/istio
            orgId: 1
            type: file
      datasources:
        datasources.yaml:
          apiVersion: 1
      env: {}
      envSecrets: {}
      image:
        repository: grafana/grafana
        tag: 7.1.3
      nodeSelector: {}
      persist: false
      podAntiAffinityLabelSelector: []
      podAntiAffinityTermLabelSelector: []
      security:
        enabled: false
        passphraseKey: passphrase
        secretName: grafana
        usernameKey: username
      service:
        annotations: {}
        externalPort: 3000
        name: http
        type: ClusterIP
      storageClassName: ""
      tolerations: []
    istiocoredns:
      coreDNSImage: coredns/coredns
      coreDNSPluginImage: istio/coredns-plugin:0.2-istio-1.1
      coreDNSTag: 1.6.2
    istiodRemote:
      injectionURL: ""
    kiali:
      contextPath: /kiali
      createDemoSecret: false
      dashboard:
        auth:
          strategy: login
        grafanaInClusterURL: http://grafana:3000
        jaegerInClusterURL: http://tracing/jaeger
        passphraseKey: passphrase
        secretName: kiali
        usernameKey: username
        viewOnlyMode: false
      hub: quay.io/kiali
      nodeSelector: {}
      podAntiAffinityLabelSelector: []
      podAntiAffinityTermLabelSelector: []
      security:
        cert_file: /kiali-cert/cert-chain.pem
        enabled: false
        private_key_file: /kiali-cert/key.pem
      service:
        annotations: {}
      tag: v1.22.1
    mixer:
      adapters:
        kubernetesenv:
          enabled: true
        prometheus:
          enabled: true
          metricsExpiryDuration: 10m
        stackdriver:
          auth:
            apiKey: ""
            appCredentials: false
            serviceAccountPath: ""
          enabled: false
          tracer:
            enabled: false
            sampleProbability: 1
        stdio:
          enabled: true
          outputAsJson: false
        useAdapterCRDs: false
      policy:
        adapters:
          kubernetesenv:
            enabled: true
          useAdapterCRDs: false
        autoscaleEnabled: false
        image: mixer
        sessionAffinityEnabled: false
      telemetry:
        autoscaleEnabled: false
        env:
          GOMAXPROCS: "6"
        image: mixer
        loadshedding:
          latencyThreshold: 100ms
          mode: enforce
        nodeSelector: {}
        podAntiAffinityLabelSelector: []
        podAntiAffinityTermLabelSelector: []
        replicaCount: 1
        sessionAffinityEnabled: false
        tolerations: []
    pilot:
      appNamespaces: []
      autoscaleEnabled: false
      autoscaleMax: 5
      autoscaleMin: 1
      configMap: true
      configNamespace: istio-config
      cpu:
        targetAverageUtilization: 80
      enableProtocolSniffingForInbound: true
      enableProtocolSniffingForOutbound: true
      env: {}
      image: pilot
      keepaliveMaxServerConnectionAge: 30m
      nodeSelector: {}
      podAntiAffinityLabelSelector: []
      podAntiAffinityTermLabelSelector: []
      policy:
        enabled: false
      replicaCount: 1
      tolerations: []
      traceSampling: 1
    prometheus:
      contextPath: /prometheus
      hub: docker.io/prom
      nodeSelector: {}
      podAntiAffinityLabelSelector: []
      podAntiAffinityTermLabelSelector: []
      provisionPrometheusCert: true
      retention: 6h
      scrapeInterval: 15s
      security:
        enabled: true
      tag: v2.15.1
      tolerations: []
    sidecarInjectorWebhook:
      enableNamespacesByDefault: false
      injectLabel: istio-injection
      objectSelector:
        autoInject: true
        enabled: false
      rewriteAppHTTPProbe: true
    telemetry:
      enabled: true
      v1:
        enabled: false
      v2:
        enabled: true
        metadataExchange: {}
        prometheus:
          enabled: true
        stackdriver:
          configOverride: {}
          enabled: false
          logging: false
          monitoring: false
          topology: false
    tracing:
      jaeger:
        hub: docker.io/jaegertracing
        memory:
          max_traces: 100000
        tag: "1.16"
        persist: true
        spanStorageType: badger
        storageClassName: "gp2"
        accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
      nodeSelector: {}
      opencensus:
        exporters:
          stackdriver:
            enable_tracing: true
        hub: docker.io/omnition
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: 2Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 400Mi
        tag: 0.1.9
      podAntiAffinityLabelSelector: []
      podAntiAffinityTermLabelSelector: []
      provider: jaeger
      service:
        annotations: {}
        externalPort: 9411
        name: http-query
        type: ClusterIP
      zipkin:
        hub: docker.io/openzipkin
        javaOptsHeap: 700
        maxSpans: 500000
        node:
          cpus: 2
        probeStartupDelay: 10
        queryPort: 9411
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
            memory: 2048Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 150m
            memory: 900Mi
        tag: 2.20.0
    version: ""
```

and this is the whole log of the command:

```
$ istioctl install istio-config.yaml

- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
- Processing resources for Istio core.
✔ Istio core installed
- Processing resources for Istiod.
- Processing resources for Istiod.
- Processing resources for Istiod.
- Processing resources for Istiod.
- Processing resources for Istiod.
- Processing resources for Istiod.
- Processing resources for Istiod.
- Processing resources for Istiod.
- Processing resources for Istiod.
- Processing resources for Istiod.
- Processing resources for Istiod.
- Processing resources for Istiod.
- Processing resources for Istiod.
- Processing resources for Istiod.
- Processing resources for Istiod.
- Processing resources for Istiod.
✔ Istiod installed
- Processing resources for Egress gateways, Ingress gateways.
- Processing resources for Egress gateways, Ingress gateways.
- Processing resources for Egress gateways, Ingress gateways.
- Processing resources for Egress gateways, Ingress gateways.
- Processing resources for Egress gateways, Ingress gateways.
- Processing resources for Egress gateways, Ingress gateways.
- Processing resources for Egress gateways, Ingress gateways.
- Processing resources for Egress gateways, Ingress gateways.
- Processing resources for Egress gateways, Ingress gateways.
✔ Egress gateways installed
- Processing resources for Ingress gateways.
✔ Ingress gateways installed
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.2021-03-08T09:26:21.151700Z   error   installer   PersistentVolumeClaim "istio-jaeger-pvc" is invalid: spec.resources.requests.storage: Forbidden: field can not be less than previous value

- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
- Processing resources for Addons.
✘ Addons encountered an error: PersistentVolumeClaim "istio-jaeger-pvc" is invalid: spec.resources.requests.storage: Forbidden: field can not be less than previous value
- Pruning removed resourcesError: failed to apply manifests: errors occurred during operation
```

This is more details about the pvc `istio-jaeger-pvc`:

```
$ kubectl get persistentvolumeclaim/istio-jaeger-pvc -n istio-system -o yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolumeClaim","metadata":{"annotations":{"volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner":"kubernetes.io/aws-ebs","volume.kubernetes.io/storage-resizer":"kubernetes.io/aws-ebs"},"finalizers":["kubernetes.io/pvc-protection"],"labels":{"app":"jaeger","install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource":"installed-state","install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource-namespace":"istio-system","operator.istio.io/component":"AddonComponents","operator.istio.io/managed":"Reconcile","operator.istio.io/version":"1.6.8","release":"istio"},"name":"istio-jaeger-pvc","namespace":"istio-system"},"spec":{"accessModes":["ReadWriteOnce"],"resources":{"requests":{"storage":"15Gi"}},"storageClassName":"gp2","volumeMode":"Filesystem"}}
    pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: "yes"
    pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: "yes"
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
    volume.kubernetes.io/selected-node: ip-10-8-121-54.eu-central-1.compute.internal
    volume.kubernetes.io/storage-resizer: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
  creationTimestamp: "2021-01-11T10:37:18Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  labels:
    app: jaeger
    install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource: installed-state
    install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource-namespace: istio-system
    operator.istio.io/component: AddonComponents
    operator.istio.io/managed: Reconcile
    operator.istio.io/version: 1.6.8
    release: istio
  name: istio-jaeger-pvc
  namespace: istio-system
  resourceVersion: "47732761"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/istio-system/persistentvolumeclaims/istio-jaeger-pvc
  uid: 66beac27-7ddb-46ce-9061-af0578bd4b89
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 15Gi
  storageClassName: gp2
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: pvc-66beac27-7ddb-46ce-9061-af0578bd4b89
status:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 15Gi
  phase: Bound
```

---

```
$ kubectl describe persistentvolumeclaim/istio-jaeger-pvc -n istio-system

Name:          istio-jaeger-pvc
Namespace:     istio-system
StorageClass:  gp2
Status:        Bound
Volume:        pvc-66beac27-7ddb-46ce-9061-af0578bd4b89
Labels:        app=jaeger
               install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource=installed-state
               install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource-namespace=istio-system
               operator.istio.io/component=AddonComponents
               operator.istio.io/managed=Reconcile
               operator.istio.io/version=1.6.8
               release=istio
Annotations:   kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                 {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolumeClaim","metadata":{"annotations":{"volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner":"kubernetes.i...
               pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
               volume.kubernetes.io/selected-node: ip-10-8-121-54.eu-central-1.compute.internal
               volume.kubernetes.io/storage-resizer: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      15Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    istio-tracing-85fb6445f-qs7qp
Events:        <none>
```

Comment: you need to get the yaml of the resource that makes the claim to see what's the value of the storage, and what previous value it is complaining about.

Comment: @suren and how to do these steps ? :p

Comment: I'd reckon the `$ kubectl get RESOURCE RESOURCE-NAME -n NAMESPACE -o yaml` and `$ kubectl describe RESOURCE RESOURCE-NAME -n NAMESPACE` should provide the needed information to debug this further. Also focusing specifically on the configuration you included I suspect that the `..tracing.jaeger.persist: true` is responsible for `PVC` creation. Please attach the output as pointed by Suren.

Comment: @DawidKruk thanks for your reply I have updated the answer please check it.

Comment: @DawidKruk and is there a way to keep or add some volume to this pvc without deleting it ? because it has 15G of data !

Comment: As I do not have any experience when it comes to AWS I cannot tell. Are you talking about the "capacity" of the PVC or the actual used space there? **Assuming that you are running this for a first time and not updating it (there is no data on PVC)**, have you tried to delete this `PVC` and run this process once again?

Comment: @DawidKruk actually I'm updating it so deleting it is not an option, but thanks for your reply I've already found the solution for it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this one is to simply increase the memory size in the `istio-config.yaml` file.
in my case, I'm updating the PVC and it looks like it's already filled with data and decreasing it wasn't an option for istio, so I increased it in the config file instead:

```
tracing:
  jaeger:
    hub: docker.io/jaegertracing
    memory:
      max_traces: 100000
    tag: "1.16"
    persist: true
    spanStorageType: badger
    storageClassName: "gp2"
    accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
  nodeSelector: {}
  opencensus:
    exporters:
      stackdriver:
        enable_tracing: true
    hub: docker.io/omnition
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "1"
        memory: 15Gi # I increased this one
      requests:
        cpu: 200m
        memory: 15Gi # and this one
```